# How to transfer everything on TFVC (2008) (Including History) to Git and eventually GitHub?

Tags: git, github, tfs, visual-studio-2008, tfvc

We are using Visual Studio 2008, and from within it, we have access to TFS (2008 version, I suppose).

I have the TFS credentials, and I would like whatever there is in the TFS server to be eventually put into a GitHub account, including the entire History.

How can I do that?

Comment: *we have access to TFS (2008 version, I suppose)*. Don't assume. Find out the actual TFS version. Visual Studio and TFS version are not tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that?

With a lot of difficulties, sweat and time...

To migrate source code I put everything I know in this documentation :

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md

But it will be difficult because TFVC 2008 doesn't support branches so it will be very difficult to migrate to git.

And I'm not sure it is really possible to migrate other things than source code...
I never heard of a tool able to do that